# Invalid CultureInfo no longer throws CultureNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net, globalization

Creating a culture info with `es-CA`, *which obviously* is incorrect **should** throw an exception, but no longer does.

This *previously* threw a `CultureNotFoundException`: `new CultureInfo("es-CA")`. It now seem to fall back to `es` with an "Unknown Locale". Although, doing something like `xy-ZZ` also works, which it's rather odd?

Why does this no longer throw an exception? Was this changed in a recent version of .NET?

**Update 1**

The documentation mentions the following:

> if the **operating system does not support that culture**, and if name is not the name of a supplementary or replacement culture, the method throws a CultureNotFoundException exception.

Testing this on Windows 7, it throws `CultureNotFoundException` but on Windows 10 it does not throw the exception.

Comment: It must exist on your machine, because the behavior hasn't changed (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky2chs3h(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria, I'm saying that it **does not** throw an exception, which it should. The culture or local does not exist on my machine.

Comment: I know, but I just wanted to let you know that the docs say it still behaves that way.

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria, Thanks! Looks like it's because of the OS... Which is a bit annoying.

Comment: The behavior has changed and you can find the info on GitHub CoreFx repo when they discussed about culture info.

Comment: @LexLi you were probably referring to this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1669

Answer (score 5):

Now add an answer based on the comments.

Due to the changes in Windows design, now there is no more "invalid culture" if the name matches BCP-47, so instead of throwing an exception .NET Framework/.NET Core accept the new culture.

You can refer to [the GitHub discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1669), and the below quote,

> As the framework depends on the OS for getting the cultures, the OS's
>   is moving to the model any BCP-47 culture name become valid even the
>   OS is not supporting it. for instance, Windows 10 is supporting any
>   well formed culture name even the OS don't have real data for such
>   culture. for example, if trying to create a culture "xx-XXXX" in
>   Windows 10 it will succeed. considering that, it doesn't make sense to
>   have culture enumeration as any set we return doesn't mean these are
>   the only supported cultures. looking at your issue, you workaround is
>   acceptable. if really want to have more better way, we can consider
>   something like CultureInfo.TryGetCulture() but as I said previously
>   moving forward almost any culture will be valid.

Comment: Hello, I have been troubled about one my unit tests starting to fail.  If parses "not-a-valid-culture" which is considered valid.  If wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag#Syntax_of_language_tags) is correct however then this should still be an invalid culture.  Anyway, thanks for the replies.  I learned that we have to roll our own validation for our cultures.

Comment: Holy hoot owl batman, this means you can create invalid `new Culture("flippidyfloop")` in one environment with no exceptions, and in another environment it throws an exception.

Answer (score 5):

I'm posting this as an answer to two questions that are *almost* asked in the OP's question-post:

> After Windows 10's breaking changes to support `BCP-47`...
>
> 1. How can I tell if a given `CultureInfo` object is a "real" Culture, or a fake/contrived/private `CultureInfo` created from-scratch in code?
> 2. How can I tell if a user-supplied `String cultureName` value is valid for  `new CultureInfo(String)` *and* that the runtime environment (.NET and/or OS) has meaningful culture data for that name (more than just the `DisplayName`)?

---

### Question 1: Validating a given `CultureInfo` instance:

[As per the documentation for `CultureTypes`, prior to Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.culturetypes?view=net-6.0), if the `CultureInfo.CultureTypes` property has the flag `UserCustomCulture` then it was a custom culture. Since Windows 10, the `UserCustomCulture` flag indicates custom cultures, but also "**system cultures that are not backed by a complete set of cultural data** and that do not have unique local identifiers".

So if you want to validate a `CultureInfo` on Windows 10 *identically* as though it were on Windows 8.1 or earlier, just check that:

1. The `CultureInfo.CultureTypes` does not have the `CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture` flag set.
2. If it *does* have `UserCustomCulture`, ensure `CultureInfo.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName != "ZZZ"`

   - The `"ZZZ"` magic-string seems to be within Windows itself, and it only appears on Windows 10 or later.
   - [.NET Core's own test-cases includes a test for it](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/47bcd1a8b053c2dcd05b47da033587199167e790/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Globalization/CultureData.Icu.cs#L344), but never explains it beyond the comment "`.GetThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName(cultureName) ?? "ZZZ" /* default lang name */;`".

So this works for me:

```cs
public static Boolean ValidateCultureInfoWithPreWindows10Logic( CultureInfo ci )
{
    Boolean hasUserCustom = ( ci.CultureTypes & CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture ) == CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture;
    if( hasUserCustom )
    {
        if( ci.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName == "ZZZ" )
        {
            // Windows doesn't have a name for this language - this CultureInfo is invalid under Windows 8.1 or earlier.
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            // The `UserCustomCulture` flag means *some* CultureData is missing, but not enough to make them useless.
            // On both Win8 and Win10, the same 8 Neutral Cultures match here: [ jv, jv-Latn, mg, nqo, sn, sn-Latn, zgh, zgh-Tfng ]
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // The `UserCustomCulture` flag is not set, which means 100% of the CultureInfo's CultureData exists in the system.
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Question 2: Validating a given `String cultureName`:

- Remember that a culture-name is hierarchical, with 3 main levels:

  - `Invariant` = `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.
  - `Neutral` = a language-name without a region, e.g. `en`, `fr`, etc.
  - `Specific` = a language-name for a specific region, e.g. `en-US`, `en-GB`, `fr-CA`, `fr-FR`.
  - Additionally there are some names for sub-specific-regions, e.g. `ca-ES-valencia`. I've never encountered more than 3 levels of depth, though.
- Validating a `cultureName` depends on what your business/domain/application requirements are:

  - If you want to require the name to match an OS-known language **and** region, then it's sufficient to do `ValidateCultureInfoWithPreWindows10Logic( new CultureInfo( cultureName ) )` (after validating that the format of `cultureName` complies with BCP-47, of course).
  - If you want to require the name to match an OS-known language, but **allow** any OS-known region to be specified, even if the OS doesn't have Specific CultureData for it (e.g. when using `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-FR")`) then checking `ci.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName != "ZZZ"` is sufficient.
  - If you want to require the name to match an OS-known language, but **allow** any region to be specified, even if the OS doesn't even know about the region, then it's complicated...

Here's a table showing results of `new CultureInfo` vs `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture` on Windows 10 vs. Server 2012 R2, and .NET 4.8 vs .NET 6:

| Expression | Windows 10 + .NET 6 | Windows 10 + .NET 4.8 | Windows 2012 R2 + .NET 4.8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CultureInfo ci1 = new CultureInfo("en-FR") |  |  |  |
| ci1.DisplayName | "English (France)" | "Unknown Locale (en-FR)" | `CultureNotFoundException` |
| ci1.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName | "ZZZ" | "ENU" | `CultureNotFoundException` |
| ci1.CultureTypes | SpecificCultures | UserCustomCulture | InstalledWin32Cultures | SpecificCultures | UserCustomCulture | `CultureNotFoundException` |
|  |  |  |  |
| CultureInfo spec = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-FR") |  |  |  |
| spec.DisplayName | "English (France)" | "Unknown Locale (en-FR)" | "English (United States)" |
| spec.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName | "ZZZ" | "ENU" | "ENU" |
| spec.CultureTypes | SpecificCultures | UserCustomCulture | InstalledWin32Cultures | SpecificCultures | UserCustomCulture | SpecificCultures | InstalledWin32Cultures | FrameworkCultures |

So far, so **very** inconsistent.

If you want to allow arbitrary language names, even if the OS doesn't know about the language (let alone the region) - be it Neutral or Specific CultureInfo... uhh... I'll have to answer that question later.

---

### Other tips: How to reliably validate `cultureName` when you want it restricted to OS-supported cultures (Neutral and/or Specific):

A quick-fix is to have this:

```cs
public static class KnownCultureInfoNameValidator
{

private static readonly HashSet<String> _preWindows10BuiltInCustomNames = new String[]
{
     "jv", "jv-Latn", "mg", "nqo", "sn", "sn-Latn", "zgh", "zgh-Tfng"
}
    .ToHashSet();

private static readonly HashSet<String> _knownLanguages = BuildHashSet( CultureInfo.GetCultures( CultureTypes.NeutralCultures ) );

private static readonly HashSet<String> _knownSpecific = BuildHashSet( CultureInfo.GetCultures( CultureTypes.SpecificCultures ) );

private static HashSet<String> BuildHashSet( IEnumerable<CultureInfo> cultures )
{
    return cultures
        .Where( ci => ci.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName != "ZZZ" )
        .Where( ci => ci.LCID != 127 ) // Exclude InvariantCulture
#if LIKE_PRE_WINDOWS_10
        .Where( ci =>
            _preWindows10BuiltInCustomNames.Contains( ci.Name )
            ||
            ( ci.CultureTypes & CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture ) == 0
        )
#endif
        .Select( ci => ci.Name )
        .ToHashSet();
}

// Only returns true if `cultureName` is an OS-known culture with sufficient OS-provided culture data. This method will return false for partially-known cultuires.
public static Boolean ValidateCultureName( String cultureName, Boolean allowNeutral, Boolean allowSpecific )
{
     if( allowNeutral && _knownLanguages.Contains( cultureName ) ) return true;

     if( allowSpecific && _knownSpecific.Contains( cultureName ) ) return true;

     return false;
}

}
```

---

### Research:

- I've been pouring over the internals of .NET's `CultureInfo` and (internal) `CultureData`, here's my findings:

  - When a `new CultureData` instance is created using any of the `String name` constructors (including internally), a new **empty** `CultureData` object is created, and then its `sRealName` and `bUseOverrides` fields set with the earlier `cultureName` and `useUserOverride` values (respectively) from the `CultureInfo`'s constructor call-site.
  - This `CultureData` is then [passed into a function `nativeInitCultureData` that's internal to the .NET CLR runtime](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/culturedata.cs,3500) (i.e. `MethodImplOptions.InternalCall`).

    - Notice how in the .NET Framework 4.8 code (i.e. the `referencesource.microsoft.com` link above) code basically assumes that `sWindowsName` is the official name for a `CultureInfo`, so provided it's non-`null` then *surely it must be good* (e.g. in `DoGetLocaleInfo`):

      > ```
      > int DoGetLocaleInfoInt(uint lctype)
      > {
      >    // Ask OS for data, note that we presume it returns success, so we have to know that
      >    // sWindowsName is valid before calling.
      >    Contract.Assert(this.sWindowsName != null, "[CultureData.DoGetLocaleInfoInt] Expected this.sWindowsName to be populated by COMNlsInfo::nativeInitCultureData already");
      >    int result = CultureInfo.nativeGetLocaleInfoExInt(this.sWindowsName, lctype);
      >
      >     return result;
      > }
      > ```
  - So we can't use `CultureInfo.LCID` because that's now `4096 == 0x1000` for system-provided, but partial, `CultureInfo` objects - just as it is for "fake" `CultureInfo` objects.
  - We can't use `CultureInfo.CompareInfo.LCID` either, because there's still a lot of "real" (but also incomplete) system-provided cultures with `0x1000` there, such as
  - So because Windows 10 now always returns a non-`null` string value for `sWindowsName` whenever any BCP-47-compliant input `cultureName` is used, that's why there's no instant way to detect "fake" vs. "real"  `CultureInfo` objects in .NET.
- So that means there's now only 2 ways to check if a given `CultureInfo` is "fake" vs. "real":

  - **Option 1:** During program start-up, build your own private immutable `HashSet<String>` of `CultureInfo` names from `CultureInfo.GetCultures` and use that to validate, see `KnownCultureInfoNameValidator` above.
  - **Option 2:** Check if `CultureInfo.EnglishName` starts with `"Unknown Locale"` and/or `CultureInfo.Parent.EnglishName` starts with `"Unknown Language"`.

    - While it always feels wrong to do compare *magic strings*, especially human-readable strings, at least `EnglishName` is always English and won't break if a user is running a non-English build of Windows, unlike with `Exception.Message`, for example.
    - There just doesn't seem to be any other *documented* hints or values that hint if a `CultureInfo`'s data is *really* system-provided or not. None of the other non-`String` members of `CultureData` seem to go with it.
    - Be sure to use a `String.StartsWith` check, *not* `String.Equals`, due to the parenthesized `CultureName` at the end.
    - I did initially think that `ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName == "ZZZ"` might work, but on my computer the `CultureInfo.GetCultures` method returns 114 neutral cultures and 326 specific cultures with `"ZZZ"` values for that property, erk.

Comment: Cheers for "ZZZ" detection for invalid language. This .NET code needs some love...

Comment: This behavior is just bizarre, and the docs are still wrong. I have found that `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(tag, true)` will throw for invalid tags, but I'm not sure how portable that is across OS's and Docker.